# How to subtract the quantity to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

In my Product table i have a quantity and declared of all columns then my second table is have CustomerOrder then they a have quantity.

To my interface in VB.NET
They input of user all of colums in CustomerOrder table and they have a quantity textbox in my interface.
My problem is how to code or how to subtract the quantity of my Product table to the textbox when i got on save button.

I want is when i input a number in textbox to interface i want to subtract in the Quantity of Product Table?

my database is Ms Access

Comment: Share the code of what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

Though you question is not quite clear and you didn't show how does you table looks like, I think basically you would like to change your product table based on the customer's orders. Following is an example based on my understanding, in your product table you got the product `apple = 100`, then your customer ordered `10`, therefore based on these two `table`, your `apple` left will be `90`, which will updates the product table to `apple=90`. If this is what you want, my suggestion to your is that you probably should build a `class` which stores all of your product data into it and build a `list (of customer class)` to keep the orders, then you write your algorithm to substrate and update your original database.